# Total Rate counter with Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to build a calculator for the rates total, but I can't figure out how to actually do it. The first column of my table is a checkbox for each entry that helps when selecting multiple entries and I know I need to make a function that will add the rates but I can't figure out how to actually parse them although I might just overthink it. I wanted to use the function count, but all I got was a counter for the clicks on the  checkboxes and I am not sure how to bring the rates in the discussion.

```
<td class="border px-4 py-2">
         <input  name="stations[]" wire:model="selected"  wire:click="count" value="{{ $station->id }}" type="checkbox">
</td>
<td wire:model="rate" value="{{ $station->SFM_rate }}"class="border px-4 py-2">{{$station->SFM_rate}}</td>
```

These are two methods that I use in the component. the delete works as expected and the count with what I have adds the sfm_rate everytime a checkbox is checked and unchecked.

```
  public $selected = [];
  public $total;
    public function deleteStations()
    {
        Station::destroy($this->selected);
    }

    public function count()
    {
        $this->total = $this->total + Station::counting($this->selected);
    }
```

And this is the method from the Station Model

```
    public static function counting($selected)
    {
        $total = Station::where('id', $selected)->value('SFM_rate');

        return $total;
    }
```

Since I managed the add part now I have to also make a method if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Where is your livewire component? Where is the livewire tag to include the component? Please post all relevant code.

Comment: Also, are you trying to add the SFM_rate value to the total count on click? It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you add an example?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for not specifying it before. The table is part of my livewire component and it is too big of a code to post the entire component, thinking that that piece would be the relevant part since it is what I would need to work on. The mechanics of it are pretty straight forward. Once I press the checkbox, the value from the sfm_rate column from that specific row/entry are added to the total. Kind of like a cart but I couldn't find an example that could help my case. Let me know of that is clearer.

Comment: I don't see you adding the SFM_rate to the total, you just call a count method on the Livewire component. Can you share the code of the count method at least? Also, you say that the table is part of your component, but it looks like the component is part of your table? If the <tr> you posted is only one line and there are multiple lines, how do you expect to add the rate to a single rate property on the component while preserving the context for the click? I am confused...

Comment: @LupinityLabs I had kind of a break-through and added what I have right now in my question. If you have any indications or a better idea I'm happy to apply it

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created this function that takes care of selecting and deselecting the checkboxes

```
    public function mount(){
        $this->total = 0;
        $this->totalList = array();
   
    }
    public function addValue($id){
        if(($key = array_search($id, $this->totalList)) !== false){
            unset($this->totalList[$key]);
            $this->total = $this->total - Station::where('id',$id)->value('SFM_rate');
        }else {
            array_push($this->totalList, $id);
            $this->total = $this->total + Station::where('id', $id)->value('SFM_rate');
        }
    }
```